# Object's values as accepted values of a let in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The idea is tell to TypeScript: "Allow the value of this let to be any of these object's values"

Hypothetical example:

```
const Types = {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  REMOVE: 'REMOVE'
}

let type: Object.values(Types) = 'ADD'
```

And when I type the code below the TypeScript show me the accepted values: 'ADD' or 'REMOVE'.

```
type = '|'
```

I can do this manually `let type: 'ADD' | 'REMOVE' = 'ADD'` but I would like it to be automatic.
Does anyone know how to do this or can you help me?

Comment: Is it important for it to be the object's _values_? The keys are all the same in this example and `keyof typeof Types` is a simple way to get that type.

Comment: Thanks @SpencerPark ! And yes, the examples I mentioned are a simplification of a code that needs to have this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent the "value types of an object" via the following type alias:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

And get then annotate your `type` variable to be `ValueOf<typeof Types>` like this:

```
let type: ValueOf<typeof Types> = "ADD"; // inferred as string
```

The `typeof Types` is necessary because `Types` is a *value* that exists at runtime, not a *type*.  To get the type corresponding to a value, you can use the `typeof` [type query operator](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript#typescripts-type-queries).

Note that frowny face, though... the problem we have is that the compiler has intepreted the `Types` object to have `string` properties, whereas you want it to treat the properties as [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  TypeScipt 3.4 has [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) which makes this easy:

```
const Types = {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  REMOVE: 'REMOVE'
} as const; // TS3.4+
// inferred as type {  readonly ADD: "ADD";  readonly REMOVE: "REMOVE"; }
```

If you are not yet using TypeScript 3.4, you can still get this behavior with a helper function like this:

```
// interpret string literal values as string literal types:
const lit = <T extends string>(x: T) => x;

const Types = {
  ADD: lit('ADD'),
  REMOVE: lit('REMOVE')
};
// inferred as type  { ADD: "ADD"; REMOVE: "REMOVE"; }
```

In either case, now the types will be inferred as you expect:

```
let type: ValueOf<typeof Types> = "ADD"; // inferred as "ADD" | "REMOVE"
```

Looks good now.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20ValueOf%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%20%0A%0A%2F%2F%20interpret%20string%20literal%20values%20as%20string%20literal%20types%3A%0Aconst%20lit%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%28x%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20x%3B%0A%0Aconst%20Types%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20ADD%3A%20lit%28%27ADD%27%29%2C%0A%20%20REMOVE%3A%20lit%28%27REMOVE%27%29%0A%7D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20inferred%20as%20type%20%20%7B%20ADD%3A%20%22ADD%22%3B%20REMOVE%3A%20%22REMOVE%22%3B%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20type%3A%20ValueOf%3Ctypeof%20Types%3E%20%3D%20%22ADD%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20as%20%22ADD%22%20%7C%20%22REMOVE%22%20%F0%9F%99%82)

Answer (score 1):

Where the key/value is the same, the solution is easy:

```
const Types = {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  REMOVE: 'REMOVE'
}

let x: keyof typeof Types = 'ADD'
```

But as you've indicated, the values in your real example are different.

You will need to introduce a union type, ideally before the object you create. The reason being, adding it after the object and not using it on the original object's type information leaves a possible gap in the type checking (it would allow me to change the value within `Types` with no errors).

I have given the values different names as using the same key/value suggests the previous fix.

```
type AddRemove = 'ADDV' | 'REMOVEV';

const Types: { [key: string]: AddRemove } = {
    ADD: 'ADDV',
    REMOVE: 'REMOVEV'
}

let x: AddRemove = 'ADDV'
```

It is possible that you may be able to solve your problem in a different way, for example using an `enum` or possible a discriminated union - it depends what you are using this for.